# Stored pybind py::object forgets its attributes

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Using pybind11, I am trying to store a python object in a C++ class in order to call its methods down the line. However the object seems to lose its attributes once stored. Is there a way to make this work ?

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

class TotoWrapper {
  private:
    py::object& toto;

  public:
    explicit TotoWrapper(py::object &toto_) : toto{toto_}  {
        toto.attr("greet")("second");
        }
    void call_toto(){toto.attr("greet")("third");}
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(PythonModule, module_handle) {
    module_handle.doc() = "Pybind test";

    py::class_<TotoWrapper>(module_handle, "TotoWrapper")
        .def(py::init<py::object&>())
        .def("call_toto", &TotoWrapper::call_toto);
}
```

```py
import outputs.python.PythonModule as pybindmodule

class Toto:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def greet(self, sth):
        print(f"Hello {sth}")
```

Then I get the following:

```bash
>>> toto = Toto()
>>> toto.greet("first")
Hello first

>>> wrapper = pybindmodule.TotoWrapper(toto)
Hello second

>>> wrapper.call_toto()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mlucas/pr6012/pubind_test/pybind_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    wrapper.call_toto()
AttributeError: 'outputs.python.PythonModule.TotoWrapper' object has no attribute 'greet'
```

Comment: Try to store it as a `py::object` without a reference. I think it is dangling reference. Python objects are ref-counted already, so `py::object` is like a shared pointer.

Comment: @unddoch I don't really understand the issue but storing the object directly does indeed solve the problem. Thank you!